# In my Blender 2.82a the snap function is not working

Tags: vertices, error, extrude, snapping

I was trying to learn Blender starting from the beginner tutorial of Blenderguru on Youtube where he tries to make a doughnut.
In one part he tries to use the snap function to make the icing droop down on doughnut. I tried my best to copy the same on my computer but instead of snapping.... the vertices merge with the underlying surface.
I don't know why. I even tried to install a previous version and check if it would work in that but it didn't.
So any help regarding that would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add some pictures please, one in solid and one in wireframe view

Answer (score 0):

While in Edit Mode for any object, open the Properties Shelf if it isn't already open (<kbd>n</kbd> key while hovering mouse in the 3D View), and click on the *Tools Tab*. Under the *Options* section, there is a feature called **Auto Merge**. Make sure it is not checked if you don't want vertices automatically merging with other vertices when they get close.

[image]

Comment: It is not checked but still, the same thing is happening